# Generate a unique PIN code based on the phone number

Tags: c#

With a unique phone number like `0241194000`, I want to generate a PIN code based on the phone number and also a way to check or validate that the PIN was really generated from the phone number.

EXAMPLE

```
Number  : 0241194000                      LENGHT(10)
PIN     : 675436                          LENGHT(6)     ONLY NUMERIC
Checker : 673AA3738SHZXCVDER              ANY LENGTH    ALPHANUMERIC.
```

Any links or help will be great.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: I cna understand generating a PIN from a phone number, but what is the checker used for?

Comment: I think the word 'unique' before 'PIN code' is open for multiple interpretations. If the PIN has to be unique in the entire system it's indeed a pigeonhole violation.

Comment: @SLaks checker it will make sure that the PIN code was generated from the phonumber.

Comment: i think i have to remove the unique PIN code and leave just UNIQUE

Comment: How secure do you want the PIN? Why not just use the last 6 digits? PS: Do to the pigeonhole principle (as others have mentioned) there is no way to guarantee no colitions no matter what algorithm you use. You would need to keep track of all the pins you've give out so far and derive/ produce a unique PIN in another way if a PIN is alreayd in use.

Comment: @Cemafor Not true, Pigeonhole principle only applies if you cannot generate more PINs than Numbers, but Numbers are limited by the phone number standard, while PINs can have any form he wants.

Comment: The proper way of doing what he wants (Have short PINs validated to test if they're real) is storing the PIN codes in a database correlated with the phone number that generated them. However he asked specifically for a method to generate PINs that are unique to each phone number.

Comment: @Meoiswa: Which he currently has set to 6 digits, less then the number size he is using (10). I guess I should have included that this applies with his current sizes.

Comment: @Cemafor, Absolutelly, thats why I specificated in my answer that the PINs must be at least as long as the phone numbers if he wants to proceed with this sort of validation

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for a mathematical **bijective function** (preferably a complex one)
that allows any Number (x) to be turned into a PIN, by means of said function

`F(Number) = PIN`

By having an bijective function, you can validate PINs by solving the equation in the opposite direction.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection

For example:

Given the function: F(Number) = Number*2

```
function GeneratePIN(Number)
    return Number*2
end

function validatePIN(PIN,Number)
    return PIN == Number*2
end
```

Comment: This solution **requires** your PIN number to be longer or the same length as your Number. Otherwise the bijection wont work, for obvious reasons.

Comment: The simplest one I can think: Added to the answer. This is obviously not a very secure generation function.

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding the correct comments above about that you can not create a unique PIN that is shorter than its source set (it boils down to hashing, which is by definition never unique), I'm assuming you mean a "code that cannot be reproduced for the phone number by an outsider, and that, given the phone number and the PIN, can be proven to be related, while accepting that the same PIN might also be valid when used with another phone number".

Assuming that, the easiest solution is to create a salted hash from the phone number. Sample pseudocode:

```
static uniqueHash = '9t45uufg92dit093ik,96igm0v9m6i09im09i309disl54923';
function createPinFromPhone(string phonenumber)
{
  string pin = '';
  do {
    hash = md5(phonenumber+uniqueHash);
    pin += extractNumbersFromString(hash);
    phonenumber = pin+hash;
  }
  while(pin.length < 6)
  return pin.subString(0, 6);
}
```

This is a (rough) example of a function that will always return the same pin code from the same phone number, and through the use of the unique secret key can never be reproduced by an outsider. Theoretically you could have an entropy problem, but not on this scale realistically.

Comment: But how can you tell if the provided PIN is actually real? By calling `createPinFromPhone()` and checking the generated PIN from the one provided by the user? (Asking this for completeness sake)

Comment: @Meoiswa we create another function that will do the validation based on the phone number and the salt value. It is good to notice that the salt generated value will be saved in the DB. given the salt number + phone number the system will return the same hash code.

Comment: @Meoiswa due to the pigeonhole problem the user always has to supply the phone number along with the PIN. As such it's easy to repeat the operation and validate the PIN to be correct because of the 'preshared key'. The salt doesn't necessarily need to go into a database, given enough entropy and proper security it can be a systemwide constant - this depends of course on the requirements of the entire system, but for most systems the overhead isn't really needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create a PIN from a phone number (where the phone number is unique and PIN is not necessarily unique), you can use one of the many hashing functions, such as CRC32, MD5, SHA1, ... and take just the number of bytes/numbers you need.

Note that it is not simple to make it secure (if you want that) since hashing functions are usually only making it harder to figure out the original value (in your case figuring out the number from the PIN) and not vice versa.